# Adding an Asterisk to required text fields in Vuetify

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'd like to add a red Asterisk on every v-text-field that has the required slot. It's doable by adding a class to every required text field, but I don't want to do it by this method.

Here's my code:

```
<v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="6" >
 <v-text-field
 label="نام انگلیسی"
 v-model="role.name"
 :rules="normalRules"
 outlined
 dir="ltr"
 dense
 required
 ></v-text-field>
</v-col>
```

And here's the DOM:

```
<div class="v-input__control">
 <div class="v-input__slot">
 <div class="v-text-field__slot">
 <label for="input-102" class="v-label theme--light">
 Last name
 </label>
 <input dir="ltr" required="required" id="input-102" type="text"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="v-text-field__details">
 <div class="v-messages theme--light">
 <div class="v-messages__wrapper"></div>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have this text field input in a separate component, in order to use in many places. You can use `v-if` on span tags that contain the asterik. Like this:

```
<v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="6" >
  <v-text-field
    v-model="role.name"
    :rules="normalRules"
    outlined
    dir="ltr"
    dense
    :required="isRequired"
    >
      <template v-slot:label>
        نام انگلیسی<span v-if="isRequired" class="red--text"> *</span>
      </template>
  </v-text-field>
</v-col>
```

Then you can pass `true` or `false` to `isRequired` as a prop from the parent component. Like this:

```
<your-text-field-input-component :isRequired="true" />
```

or

```
<your-text-field-input-component :isRequired="false" />
```

Don't forget to specify the prop `isRequired` in your text field component:

```
<script>
export default {
  ...
  props: {
    isRequired: {
      type: Boolean
    }
  },
  ...
}
</script>
```